# Nvidia X Server not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I installed the recommended drivers nvidia-driver-430 for GTX1650. Reboot and it's not working.

code: nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.26       Driver Version: 430.26       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   36C    P8     1W /  N/A |      0MiB /  3911MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

code: nvidia-settings

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

(nvidia-settings:10483): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:19:08.245: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 11:19:08.248: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 11:19:08.248: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I'm a beginner and I will be grateful for any help. If you know the answer, tell me **step by step** what I should do. THX

Comment: Can You add more information about what is actually happening ? Maybe You have installed the nvidia driver but it is simply not being used. Run `lsmod | grep -i nvidia` to see if nvidia kernel module is being loaded.

Comment: code: lsmod | grep -i nvidia

`nvidia_uvm            815104  0
nvidia_drm             40960  0
nvidia_modeset       1110016  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              18792448  21 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   458752  3 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia`

Comment: Run this to obtain device id `lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'` (for me it is `01:00.0`) then run `sudo lspci -v -s 01:00.0` and search for `Kernel driver in use:`.

Comment: i have `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`

Comment: When I am looking for drivers on GeForce,com it shows me for my GTX1650(notebooks) drivers 430.09 not 430.26. Can it be a reason that it does not work?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in `nvidia-smi` tool : https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1050968/linux/nvidia-smi-quot-no-devices-were-found-quot-ubuntu-18-04/ , check if You have direct rendering enabled `$ glxinfo | grep -i "direct rendering"
direct rendering: Yes`.

Comment: (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1057156/notebook-witch-ryzen-5-and-gtx-1650-installed-drivers-does-not-work/?offset=1#5360133)  at this moment i stuck installing kernel, when reboot it show: '`błąd: boot/vmlinuz-5.1.16-050116-lowlatency has inwalid signatur` 
`bład: najpierw należy wczytać jądro`'

Comment: Turn off `secure boot` in `bios`.

Comment: it booting with 'Secure Boot' disabled, but how can I sign the kernel and re-enable "boot secure' ?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz You should have started with that ;)